# Redirecting with Raise ActiveRecord::Rollback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I can't redirect correctly, it keeps throwing me `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` but it should be redirecting `:back` to the original page.

```
def create_multiple
   Product.transaction do 
     begin
       @products = current_user.products.create!(params[:products].map { |_k, p| p.merge params[:product] })
         redirect_to :back, :notice => "Success!"
       rescue ActiveRecord::Rollback
         redirect_to :back, :notice => "An error occured, please try again."
       end
     end
   end
end
```

How do I get it to redirect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to catch the ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid exception, then why aren't you rescuing that instead of ActiveRecord::Rollback?

```
def create_multiple
  Product.transaction do
    @products = current_user.products.create! ...
  end
  notice = "Success!"
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  notice = "An error occurred, please try again"
ensure
  redirect_to :back, :notice => notice
end
```

I would write this function something like the above.

Comment: That's great! I am still new to Rails so I wasn't sure. Just going by the Transaction doc. Which says you can also use `ActiveRecord::Rollback` when using transactions: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html. Anyways, thank you.